# How can I wait till ten tasks are completed then execute the next ten tasks

Tags: c#, task

I'm accessing a web service, which has a limit of requests, you can make per minute. I have to access X > 10 entries, but am only allowed to make 10 per minute.

I realized the service as a Singleton, which can be accessed from different parts of the code. Now I need a way to know, how many request were made and whether I am allowed to make a new one.

Therefore I made a little sample code which adds 100 tasks. Each task has a delay of 3 seconds and a `Task` can only be executed when there haven't been ten tasks before by using `Task.WhenAny`. However I get an "`An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code`" exception when I remove the completed task from the list.

How can I fix this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Test
    {
        private static Test instance;
        public static Test Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new Test();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }


        private List<Task> taskPool = new List<Task>();
        private Test()
        {

        }

        public async void AddTask(int count)
        {
            // wait till less then then tasks are in the list
            while (taskPool.Count >= 10)
            {
                var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(taskPool);
                taskPool.Remove(completedTask);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", count, DateTime.Now);

            taskPool.Add(Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the stacktrace?

Comment: you mean the call stack. Well it is pretty unimpressive

Comment: No, i mean the stacktrace of the exception

Comment: Well it is in german, so it says, that the order of the list has been changed (which makes sense since I'm adding and removing items)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good old Sempahore solved my problem. This was a classic threading problem and there are a few tested concepts how to solve it and this is the one I'm using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Test
    {
        private static Test instance;
        public static Test Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new Test();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }

        private static Semaphore _pool = new Semaphore(0, 10);
        private Test()
        {
            _pool.Release(10);
        }

        public async void AddTask(int count)
        {   
            _pool.WaitOne();
            var task = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", count, DateTime.Now);
            await task;
            _pool.Release();
        }
    }
}
```